# Terminal showing path while debugging Python code in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal, path

I am just a newbie and whenever I debug my code. This shows up with my output. How can I hide these unnecessary paths.
PS C:\Users\apoor\Desktop\Python\oops> & ***C:/Users/apoor/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/apoor/Desktop/Python/oops/overridingMethods.py***

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please set it in "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations)" in Visual Studio Code:

```
 "console": "internalConsole",
```

It will display the debugging results on the Visual Studio Code internal console and not display the path.

[image]

Update:

At present, there is no direct way to hide the running path of the internal terminal of VSCode, because it integrates the powershell or cmd terminal from the computer, we need to specify the Python path used and the path to execute the script for it.

In addition, you could also try to use VSCode's extension "Code Runner".

More reference: [Console in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).

Comment: How can I avoid the path in terminal when I simply run the python file?